# Does changing only the type of a column in a migration in Sequelize keep its original constraints?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am working on a Express project and using Sequelize as my ORM, and I have the following Sequelize model defined:

```
Field.init({
  type: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,    
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
  }
}, {
  sequelize,   
  underscored: true,
  tableName: "field",
});
```

Let's say now I want to limit the amount of characters for the type column and create a migration such as the following (`async up` is the focus in here):

```
'use strict';
const { Transaction } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.transaction({
      isolationLevel: Transaction.ISOLATION_LEVELS.SERIALIZABLE,
    }, async t => {
        await queryInterface.changeColumn('field', 'type', {
                type: Sequelize.STRING(400),
                allowNull: false,
            },
            { transaction: t },
        );
    });
  },

  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.transaction({
      isolationLevel: Transaction.ISOLATION_LEVELS.SERIALIZABLE,
    }, async t => {
        await queryInterface.changeColumn('field', 'type', {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,    
                allowNull: false,
            },
            { transaction: t },
        );
    });
  }
};
```

Will the `unique` and `allowNull` constraints remain for the column? Or will these be dropped because in the migration I only listed the new type of my column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In Sequelize migrations, **adding a new constraint does not automatically remove old constraints**.
- When you create a new migration to add a constraint, **it will add the specified constraint without affecting any existing constraints** unless you explicitly remove them in the same or a separate migration.

Comment: Thanks! I do confirm what you said. Regards